# Tehillim / special prayers during pregnancy

Tags: tefilla, tehillim

What special Tehillim/prayers should be said during pregnancy?

Comment: No judgements at all, but given that the baby will not be Jewish, you must seek personal guidance from a local Rabbi about questions like this.

Comment: Maybe try a book like this? https://www.eichlers.com/aneni-special-prayers-for-special-occasions-h-c-pocketsize.html

Comment: But in general ... just bless God, make requests of God, and thank God. Great formula.

Comment: This site is for answering general questions, not personally-tailored advice. If you simply ask "what Tehilim and prayers are recommended for expecting parents?", you're likely to get a better response.

Comment: A personal heartfelt prayer in your own words is always good.  I'm not saying that others might not be even better though